# json python converting issue

Tags: python, json, type-conversion

I have a (probably malformed) string I need to convert to the json format. Printing out the string I get

```
{"composemsg":{"return":null,"report":"<p class=\"error j-table-ui-report-entry\">07:39:28 - Action failed<br\/>Error adding row 0<br\/> Message <span class=\"label\">\"Test Message\"<\/span>,  Receivers 'Array\n(\n    [0] => gaga7\n)\n'<br\/><\/p>",0:""}}
```

ADDED: I have no way to modify this string in the first place or to change the code that produces this string. All I have is the string as quoted above!

When trying to convert the string (contained in the variable 'j') using

```
json.loads(j)
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 250 (char 250)
```

However, when starting python on the command line and asserting a variable to the printed-out string (replacing 'null' by 'None'), it works fine:

```
In [40]: x = {"composemsg":{"return":None,"report":"<p class=\"error j-table-ui-report-entry\">07:39:28 - Action failed<br\/>Error adding row 0<br\/> Message <span class=\"label\">\"Test Message\"<\/span>,  Receivers 'Array\n(\n    [0] => gaga7\n)\n'<br\/><\/p>",0:""}}
In [41]: x
Out[41]: 
{'composemsg': {0: '','report': '<p class="error j-table-ui-report-entry">07:39:28 - Action failed<br\\/>Error adding row 0<br\\/> Message <span class="label">"Test Message<\\/span>,  Receivers \'Array\n(\n    [0] => gaga7\n)\n\'<br\\/><\\/p>', 'return': None}}
```

Any ideas of this behavior? Is there a malformed place in the original string? I do not see any issues.

Comment: If there were some answers to some question I would accept them of course...

Comment: I see six questions with eleven answers, none of which you accepted.

Comment: I only can accept an answer if it solves my problem. Should I mark the unanswered questions as 'unimportant' or something?

Comment: @Alex Only accept answers which solved your problems. If you've done that, then there is no problem at all. Don't ever feel pushed into accepting something you don't really want to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON object property names should be strings. From http://www.json.org/:

[image]

The error message is pointing that you have an unquoted property name at the position 250 (the 0 key).

It may be hard to figure out because `{0:""}` is valid both in Javascript and Python (but isn't legal JSON).

Comment: So it means the original string is a malformed string and not a legal json format string? The error is in the code that create this string?

Comment: @Alex: the string is legal JS but not legal JSON.

Comment: @Alex ... yes, its not legal JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As you are escaping quotation marks, you should use raw strings to make the processing easier.

Furthermore, at the end of the string you have an attribute `0` which is not inside quotation marks.

Here's a version that works for me:

```
>>> x = r"""{
...     "composemsg": {
...         "return": null,
...         "report": "<p class=\"error j-table-ui-report-entry\">07:39:28 - Action failed<br\/>Error adding row 0<br\/> Message <span class=\"label\">\"Test Message\"<\/span>, Receivers 'Array\n(\n    [0] => gaga7\n)\n'<br\/><\/p>",
...         "0": ""
...     }
... }"""
>>> json.loads(x)
{u'composemsg': {u'report': u'<p class="error j-table-ui-report-entry">07:39:28 - Action failed<br/>Error adding row 0<br/> Message <span class="label">"Test Message"</span>, Receivers \'Array\n(\n    [0] => gaga7\n)\n\'<br/></p>', u'0': u'', u'return': None}}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer. The original string I quoted above is all I have - I have no means to change the content of that string. I only can use it as it is in order to convert it to a json format. Or should I do something like x = r"""%s"""%s??